# Use function in prediction object

Tags: r

I am trying to find out how to create a function that will be usable in the standard predict function of **R**.

Example:

```
someFunction <- function(x){
                            vec <- 4
                            ans <- cbind(x, vec)
                            return(ans)
}

newIris <- predict(someFunction, iris)
```

I guess this has something to do with either S3 or S4 classes in **R** related to functional programming in **R**, but I have yet to find a simple explanation regarding this question.

Answer (score 0):

`predict` is not generally applied to a function. It is applied to a prediction model. There are lots of different types of those, so there are lots of different version of `predict`. `methods(predict)` will show you which classes have prediction functions available.

```
methods(predict)
 [1] predict.ar*                predict.Arima*            
 [3] predict.arima0*            predict.glm               
 [5] predict.HoltWinters*       predict.lm                
 [7] predict.loess*             predict.mlm*              
 [9] predict.nls*               predict.poly*             
[11] predict.ppr*               predict.prcomp*           
[13] predict.princomp*          predict.smooth.spline*    
[15] predict.smooth.spline.fit* predict.StructTS*
```

For example, if you make a linear model using `lm`

```
LMI = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris[,1:4])
class(LMI)
[1] "lm"
```

the class of the model is `lm` so `predict(LMI)` will use the method `predict.lm`.  If you load packages, additional prediction methods may be added. For example, if you load the rpart package with `library(rpart)` a `predict.rpart` method will be added to the list.

If you want to define your own prediction method, you probably should define your own model class and then create a prediction method specific to your class. It might be a good idea to look at the source code for some of the existing predict methods. So, for example,  try typing `predict.lm`

In short,  `predict` looks at the class of the object (model) and chooses the corresponding predict method. This prediction method must be supplied for each class to which you want to apply `predict`.